# How to extract data from ODBII?

Tags: obd-ii

I bought a [EvZ Mini Interface Works on Android Torque Bluetooth Obd2/obdii Car Diagnostic Scanner (Mini)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OXPXUAK), a [PWOW® WIFI Wireless OBD2, OBDII Car Auto Diagnostic Scanner Adapter Reader, ELM327 for iPhone4S/5 iPad4 iPad mini and PC in XP System, with Micro Disc](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MP6GSWQ) and a New Version V1.5 ELM327 OBDII OBD2 Bluetooth Car Diagnostic Interface Scanner because I want to code an application like OBD Auto Doctor. But first I'm trying to extract data from the car to some archive where I can process it. How can I do it?

Comment: You should have several options in your os menu to "export as '' " or "save log." There's some horsepower calculators online if you take some of your torque readings... should have to enter some vehicle information like curb weight, a cars weight when full of fluids, and exact wheel dimensions in the program for hp data. Every gear has it's point of highest torque.

Answer (score 1):

OBD II is a  standard. All the PIDs and the relavant formulas are available online. There is also a wiki on OBD II pids. The protocol to look for depends on whether your OBD is based in CAN or K-line